# Keycloak Userstorage SPI: Provider not found?

Tags: keycloak

What are the requirments to make the Keycloak 17.0.0 find the provider?

`[error]: Build step org.keycloak.quarkus.deployment.KeycloakProcessor#configureProviders threw an exception: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProviderFactory: Provider my.own.package.UserStorageProviderFactoryImpl not found`

If I clone the project from baeldung and I start the keycloak, it works. It finds the provider. (https://www.baeldung.com/java-keycloak-custom-user-providers)

As I see the followings have to happen to make it work:

- have a class that implements the `UserStorageProviderFactory` interface:

`public class UserStorageProviderFactoryImpl implements UserStorageProviderFactory<MyImplementation> {}`

- create the `META-INF` and `services` folders and create the `org.keycloak.storage.UserStorageProviderFactory` file that contains the path to given factory:

[image]
[image]

- mvn clean package --> copy jar to Keycloak/providers and should work

What do I miss? What is extra in the baeldung project that make it work while my project is not found when I start the keycloak?

https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_user-storage-spi

Comment: I think you need to run bin/kc.sh build

Answer (score 1):

Your class should be name SomethingUserStorageProviderFactory without the word 'impl'. Your provider class should have the same pattern name, for example, SomethingUserStorageProvider.
Official documentation gives more interesting information’s (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/#_providers) and if you take a look at baeldung's code, he due the same pattern name.